# Avoid double titlebar in GNOME apps running under Xfce?

Tags: gnome, xfce, titlebar

When I run GNOME (gtk3?) apps under Xfce, they get a double titlebar:

[image: xfce vs gnome screenshot]

Is there any way to avoid this under Xfce?

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hi, the image is too small, can you provide a larger version ?
Also which version of Ubuntu are you running ?

Comment: You should be able to upload a full-suze image through the [edit] screen rather than using a third party.

Comment: Oli: I tried the "edit" thing, but it just uploads to another third party (imgur). NGRhodes: you can just right-click and "show image" to show the large image

Comment: Just a heads up, having the same issue on Gentoo and Xfce with apps compiled against GTK+ 3. No idea what's causing it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known xfwm defect](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10631) (arguably; I'd say the defect is in GTK+ 3). Fix proposed but not merged yet (as of June 18, 2014).

Comment: This answer may be outdated, since the linked thread mentioned that it is "fixed in gtk instead". But I can't find any proof that it has been fixed (at least not in Xubuntu 14.04.3 yet, as I have updated on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the Composition from 'Window Manager Tweaks', this helped on Debian Jessie's XFCE.